# Get Ping Stats From Resource Monitor (Python)

Tags: python, statistics, ping, resource-monitor

Recently I found that there was no way to get the ping to a Grand Theft Auto Online session other than to open Resource Monitor, open TCP/IP Connections and view it from there. This sparked an idea to create a python script to retrieve the ping data from GTA5.exe and display it on the screen.

Is this even possible with python and is this the best way to do it? Any ideas or help is appreciated.

I know its possible to ping an IP Address with the `os` module in python, but since GTAO is a P2P connection there is no single IP Address.

Comment: What do you mean by "the ping to a Grand Theft Auto Online session?" Do you mean you want to programmatically obtain the current ping of the connection to the GTA online server that your game is connected to? That's going to be very OS dependent. It's sounds like you're on windows. https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html might mention some packages that provide API access to the same information that resource monitor uses.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean and yep I am on windows.